# Bitbuket pipeline pytest issue

Tags: yaml, pytest, bitbucket, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a test folder in my directory under tests/test_main.py, in this file I am calling the pytest feature within an if statement as follows;

```
- if python3.9 -m pytest; then
     echo "Tests passed";
  else 
     echo "Tests failed";
```

The first time I committed this code I received an all tests passes 8/8 which was expected. The following run I added a function to my test_main.py file that was a simple test that would fail assert 2+2 = 5. When committing by code everything run fine but this change was not picked up - still received an 8/8 passed. Then I tried changing one of the functions that previously passed to fail and still was not picked up.

This is the test function I added

```
# Test that should fail
def test_example():
    assert 2 + 2 == 5
```

I am thinking there might be a cache that bitbucket applies that I cannot seem to get my head around?

This is the start of my test bitbucket-pipelines.yml file

```
image: python:3.9

pipelines:
  branches:
    dev:
      - step:
          name: Build and Deploy - Dev
          services:
            - docker
          script:
            - echo "Setting environment variables"
```

Everything I tried was stated above. Any help would be great!